# User input as string cannot be used to call variable in a class

Tags: python, class, variables, input, methods

Not sure I am even asking the question correctly, but I will explain. I have created a class, and I have created instances in that class, the problem is I want to be able to use an instance which is chosen by the user via input. Let's say I would like to create a chess game. I want to be able to move a piece forward (possibly backward), left, and right. Suppose I have already created a method inside the class to move the piece and each piece has a name, x-coord, and y-coord. This is the issue I get

```
class Piece(object):
    def __init__(self, x , y):
         self.x = x
         self.y = y

    def move(self, amount, direction):
         if direction == 'right':
            self.x = self.x + amount
         if direction == 'left':
            self.x = self.x - amount
         if direction == 'up':
            self.y = self.y + amount
         if direction == 'down':
            self.y = self.y - amount

rook = Piece(0,0)

piece = input('What piece would you like to move?')

#Assume that the user types rook after this prompt

piece.move(4,'right')
```

Now I get an error because the input which is assigned to the variable piece is a string, and when I need rook.move, I am actually getting 'rook'.move 
I understand variables can be changed using int(var), float(var), str(var), but how would one go about changing a variable to a class variable.

Comment: Can you post the rest of your code, including the error? It's never a bad idea to include as much information as possible, and it might clarify a bit more about what you're hoping to do.

Comment: Please mark my answer as correct if it helped you :)

Comment: Yup, your update to your question is what I suspected :) My answer should solve your problem just fine.

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: @Yes imeighteen - Please check my answer, allows you to take a string and call its class equivalent. Hope it helped, if so please mark as correct.

Comment: I'm still thinking you've got "objects" and "classes" mixed up in your mind. Why would you need to do this? Can you give some more context? Where do you store your pieces and for what purpose?

Comment: So you're using `locals` now. What's your question again?

Comment: Ah you're getting a `KeyError`. Please accept my answer now.

Answer (score 1):

A way would be to have a dictionary that maps the piece names to your classes.

So

```
pieces = {
    'Queen': Piece(0,0),
    'Tower': Piece(0,0),
    'Rook' Piece(0,0)
}

inp = input('Which piece would you like to move?')

if inp in pieces:
    pieces[inp]().move(4, right)
else:
    print('No such piece: %s - Valid pieces: %s' % (inp, pieces.keys()))
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, and I actually should have mentioned I am aware of eval(), but since I am currently in school, and need to form good practices that my professors would approve of I must do my best to avoid anything that is "not good to do". This is because I plan to continue coding in the future and rather than develop a poor habit in the foundation of coding/programming and simply cut a corner on this specific issue. I would like to find a more acceptable method of solving this issue, but thank you, I truly appreciate your response. Also I would like to add, I didn't downvote.

Comment: There are two answers

Comment: You dont need to use the eval, you can use the dictionary map

Comment: @Yes imeighteen Please check answer again :)

Comment: This looks more reasonable.

Comment: @Yes imeighteen advantage of this answer is that you can output which pieces are valid. Also, with Sebastians answer, if the user inputs a piece that does not exist, program will crash

Comment: sorry, once again. I agree you could use the dictionary, but this was prohibited by my professor when using classes, because "it defeats the purpose of using object classes ". Also as much as I try to up vote, I cannot. Unfortunately I get an error letting me know my account is too young for up voting.

Comment: Again, you're not clear on the distinction between objects and classes. Which one do you mean?

Comment: classes I believe. It would be better if I could post my code, but it is not working for some reason.